# all same value in arrays php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to echo variable `$total` when all value in array1 equal to array2 if array1 any one value not match in array2 then not show $total is equal to 3 if all equal then show 3.

Any solution?

Code:

```
$array1 = array( "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array( "green", "yellow", "red");
$total = 0;
foreach ($array1 as $txt1 => $val1) {
    foreach ($array2 as $txt2 => $val2) {
        if ($val1 == $val2) {
            $total = 3;
        }
    }
}
echo $total;
```

Comment: Just use comparison operator, no loop required: https://3v4l.org/BYhUk

Comment: comparison operator not work and i want to through loop because my array is sometime different like array( "green=>2", "red=>4", "blue");

Comment: i want to match all value one array to another array

Comment: Please add more examples.

Comment: i want when all value from array1 match to array2 then count total if anyone not match not count and simply echo 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@scaisEdge code assumes you are matching element 0 with element 0, element 1 with element 1 etc.

The following code sample will check the values exist *anywhere* in the other array.

```
$array1 = array("green", "yellow", "blue");
$array2 = array("green", "red", "blue");

$total = 0;
foreach ($array1 as $a1) {
    foreach ($array2 as $a2) {
        if ($a1 == $a2) {
            $total++;
        }
    }
}
echo $total;
```

---

**Edit** following comment:

```
$total = 0;
if ($array1 == $array2) {
    $total = count($array1);
}
echo $total
```

The above code will echo the number of elements from the array if the arrays are identical, otherwise it will echo 0.

---

**Edit2**: the above is wrong.

Replacing the final echo statement from my original answer with the following line.  (The original answer being the one at the top, with two foreach loops).

```
echo $total == count($array1) ? 3 : 0;
```

This will check how many elements were the same, and if it is the same amount of elements as there are in `$array1` then it will print 3, otherwise, it will print 0. This is a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Comment: i want when all value from array1 match to array2 then count total if anyone not match not count and simply echo 0

Comment: friend its not correct, i want i want when all value from array1 match to array2 then in my code echo 3 simple but if not match any for exmaple array1 have yellow value and in array2 have not yellow value so its not match and not echo 3 only echo 0 if the value is same on both side then echo simply 3 ... i clear the question plz any help

Comment: @opangmario Apologies, I was under the impression that the number 3 came from the number of elements. Just replace `count($array1)` with `3`...?

Comment: i not counting anything just check all value same in array1 and array2 then echo 3 otherwise echo 0 .my array sometime different so i only match value on both side sometime have key and value pair but i want only match value .

Comment: i replace but when both array have same value not echo 3

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is PHP built in function for array for differentiate twi arrays.

```
array_diff($a1,$a2);
```

I think this will help you out this function return array value and if it return empty array it means both array are same.
you can see briefly use here
[array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$array1 = array( "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array( "green", "yellow", "red");
$total = 0;
$result=array_diff($array1,$array2);
if(empty($result))
  $total = 3;
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but looking to you sample you could use a single foreach and count the row that match 
and then echo the resulting total  or test the final result for more ..

```
  $array1 = array( "green", "red", "blue");
  $array2 = array( "green", "yellow", "red");
  $total = 0;
  foreach ($array1 as $key => $val1) {
    if ($val1 == $array2[$key]){
      $total++;
    }

  }

  if ($total !=3) {
     echo 0;
  } else {
     echo $total;
  }
```

Comment: i want when all value from array1 match to array2 then count total if anyone not match not count and simply echo 0

Comment: Simple `echo count(array_intersect($array1, $array2));` would do the same.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone   correct .. you should post a proper answer .. is a good answer ..

Answer (score 0):

as i read your conversation you just want to check if all are match and if not 
 return 0 then try this:

```
$array1 = array( "green", "red", "blue");
  $array2 = array( "green", "yellow", "red");
  $total = 3;
  foreach ($array1 as $key => $val) {
   if (!in_array($val, $array2)){
      $total = 0;
    }

}

echo $total;
```